# How can I have a stream provider which needs a user id?

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I have a multiprovider that has an authentication provider and a user providerm and is wrapped around the main app. The authentication provider has an async method that returns a `Future<AuthenticationCertificate>`. The user provider has a stream that needs that authentication certificate. So how can I get the certificate into my user provider?

**This is my multiprovider which is wrapped around the main app**

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<PreferencesProvider>(
        create: (_) => PreferencesProvider()),
    Provider<AuthenticationProvider>(create: (_) => AuthenticationProvider(),),
    Provider<GroupProvider>(create: (_) => GroupProvider()),
    Provider<UserProvider>(
      create: (_) => UserProvider(),
    ),
    StreamProvider(create: (context) {
      return Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).authenticatedUserStream(Provider.of<AuthenticationProvider>(context).userAuthenticationCertificate());
    }),
  ],
```

**This is my authentication provider**

```
class AuthenticationProvider {
  final FirebaseAuth _authentication = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String _smsCode;
  String _verificationID;

  Future<void> registerWithPhone(
      {String phoneNumber = '',
      BuildContext context,
      Function(AuthCredential, BuildContext) onLogin,
      Function(AuthException, BuildContext) onLoginFailed}) async {
    String localizedPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.toString();

    return await _authentication.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: localizedPhoneNumber,
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 30),
        verificationCompleted: (authCredential) =>
            _verificationComplete(authCredential, context, onLogin),
        verificationFailed: (authException) =>
            _verificationFailed(authException, context, onLoginFailed),
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) =>
            _codeAutoRetrievalTimeout(verificationId),
        codeSent: (verificationId, [code]) =>
            _smsCodeSent(verificationId, [code]));
  }

  _verificationComplete(AuthCredential authCredential, BuildContext context,
      Function(AuthCredential, BuildContext) onLogin) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithCredential(authCredential)
        .then((authResult) {
      onLogin(authCredential, context);
    });
  }

  _verificationFailed(AuthException exception, BuildContext context,
      Function(AuthException, BuildContext) onLoginFailed) {
    onLoginFailed(exception, context);
  }

  _smsCodeSent(String verificationId, List<int> code) {
    _smsCode = verificationId;
  }

  _codeAutoRetrievalTimeout(String verificationId) {
    _smsCode = verificationId;
  }

  Future<bool> isSignedIn() async {
    return await _authentication.currentUser() != null;
  }

  Future<UserAuthenticationCertificate> userAuthenticationCertificate() async
  {
    FirebaseUser authenticatedUser = await _authentication.currentUser();
    if(authenticatedUser != null)
      return UserAuthenticationCertificate.fromFirebase(authenticatedUser);
    return null;
  }

  Future deleteAuthenticatedUser() async
  {
    FirebaseUser authenticatedUser = await _authentication.currentUser();
    if(authenticatedUser != null)
      return authenticatedUser.delete();
    return null;
  }
}
```

**And this is my user provider**

```
class UserProvider {
  static const userCollectionKey = 'users';
  final CollectionReference userCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection(userCollectionKey);

  Stream<UserModel> authenticatedUserStream(UserAuthenticationCertificate certificate) {
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> userData = userCollection.document(certificate.userID).snapshots();
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> privateUserData = userCollection.document(certificate.userID).collection('private').document('data').snapshots();
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> publicUserData = userCollection.document(certificate.userID).collection('public').document('data').snapshots();
    return CombineLatestStream([userData, privateUserData, publicUserData], (values) => values.toList()).asBroadcastStream().map((snapshot) => UserModel.fromFirebase(snapshot));
  }
}
```

**And this is the authentication certificate**

```
class UserAuthenticationCertificate
{
  String _userID;

  String get userID{
    return _userID;
  }

  UserAuthenticationCertificate._internal(this._userID);

  factory UserAuthenticationCertificate.fromFirebase(FirebaseUser firebaseUser)
  {
    return UserAuthenticationCertificate._internal(
      firebaseUser.uid
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is when I want to define my stream provider

```
StreamProvider(create: (context) {
  return Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).authenticatedUserStream(Provider.of<AuthenticationProvider>(context).userAuthenticationCertificate());
}),
```

There is an error because the userAuthenticationCertificate() is async. And also could return null if the user is not logged in. How can I deal with his problem?

**Edit**

This is what I currently have which does not throw a intelisense error

```
  Stream<UserModel> authenticatedUserStream(Future<UserAuthenticationCertificate> certificateFuture) async* {
    UserAuthenticationCertificate certificate = await certificateFuture;
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> userData = userCollection.document(certificate.userID).snapshots();
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> privateUserData = userCollection.document(certificate.userID).collection('private').document('data').snapshots();
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> publicUserData = userCollection.document(certificate.userID).collection('public').document('data').snapshots();
    yield* CombineLatestStream([userData, privateUserData, publicUserData], (values) => values.toList()).asBroadcastStream().map((snapshot) => UserModel.fromFirebase(snapshot));
  }
```

But when I try to use the provider in a child widget

```
class _ProfileListState extends State<ProfileList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userModel = Provider.of<UserModel>(context);
    return MediaQuery.removePadding(
        context: context,
        removeTop: true,
        removeLeft: true,
        removeRight: true,
        child: ListView.separated(
            itemCount: 3,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                Divider(height: 1.0),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return [
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Name',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                  ),
                  trailing: Text(
                    userModel.name,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Phone Number',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                  ),
                  trailing: Text(
                    userModel.phoneNumber,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Delete',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(
                    Icons.delete,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  onTap: () => print('delete'),
                ),
              ][index];
            }));
  }
}
```

The line `final userModel = Provider.of<UserModel>(context);` throws the following error

[image]

Comment: *"There is an error because the userAuthenticationCertificate() is async"* - so change `Stream<UserModel> authenticatedUserStream(UserAuthenticationCertificate certificate) {` to `Stream<UserModel> authenticatedUserStream(Future<UserAuthenticationCertificate> certificateFuture) {` - if your method is async you still can pass it and use `Future` API or `await` to get the real data inside `authenticatedUserStream` method

Comment: Yes but then I need to await the that method so I need to make the stream method async and I need to return a Future<Stream> which provider doesn't seem to like. How can I deal with that?

Comment: you can still use `StreamController` (and `Future.then()`), more [here](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#using-a-streamcontroller) or `async*` method signature that returns `Stream<T>` - i already said that in your previous post

Comment: Aah okay I'm going to look into that right now. My bad I thought this was a different problem entirely.

Comment: like: `Stream<int> foo(Future<int> f) async* {
  print('waiting for future...');
  var i = await f;
  print('i: $i');
  yield* Stream.fromIterable([i, i+1, i+5]);
}
var future = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => 10);
foo(future).listen(print);`

Comment: Hi I edited my post, intellisense no longer throws an error but now when I try to use the provider in a child widget I an error gets throws. Would you happen to know why? It suggest that I set listen to false but I want to keep listening to the stream, how could I solve this? Also I did try to set listen to false but it did not change anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210334/discussion-between-mike-ottink-and-pskink).

Comment: seems like `Provider` issue and i have no deep knowledge of it, does it happen if you use `StreamCompleter` too (instead of `async*` / `yield*`)?

Comment: Haven't been able to look at it yet I will do today I'll let you know. I was also thinking of using BLOC's for my streams it seems easier for streams to manage the state of the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the StreamProvider from the multi-provider list and wrap it around the class that needs it at creation.

```
class ProfileList extends StatefulWidget {
  static Widget create(BuildContext context) {
    final cert = Provider.of<AuthenticationProvider>(context)
        .userAuthenticationCertificate();

    return StreamProvider(
      create: (context) {
        return Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).authenticatedUserStream(cert);
      },
      child: ProfileList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  _ProfileListState createState() => _ProfileListState();
}

class _ProfileListState extends State<ProfileList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you can call the ProfileList like `ProfileList.create(context)` in the place of `ProfileList()`